# After Pause , Resume downloading file is not working in IE in case of large encrypted file(e.g 10Gb) , its working fine in Chrome

Tags: java, internet-explorer, https, download

Recently I have implemented Pause/Resume for downloading in java application. Its working fine in chrome , but not in IE when user download large file (e.g 10GB) . I found out that when user resume download from IE , decryption of file takes place and it takes some time so it throws error client abort exception. but I wonder how come it works fine in Chrome. Hence i feel something need to be implemented for IE specific.

I have used all below header for enabling pause resume ,

```
response.setHeader("content-length",xyz);
response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", xyz);
response.setContentType("application/x-download");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=xyz");
response.setBufferSize(xyz);
response.setHeader("etag", xyz);
response.setDateHeader("last-modified", xyz);
response.setHeader("content-range", xyz);
response.setHeader("content-Length", xyz);
```

Comment: I think that it may be because of the IE limitation. About resuming the download it get decrypted in IE, why do you think the file is decrypted? Could you please provide the detailed codes which could reprodcue your issue? Besides, could you also provide the version of IE you're using?

Comment: @JeniferJiang decryption in my application I am talking about not in IE. When user click on resume , action gets called in web app which then taking some time to decrypt file & IE I guess aborting connection as server is taking some time